# Фон под текстом

Tags: css

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такой фон под текстом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то что нашел поиском, не совсем похоже

```css
div{
  max-width: 600px
}
p {
  text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 52px;
 font-weight: 900;
 display: inline;
 color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}
h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 52px;
 font-weight: 900;
 display: inline;
 color: #fff;
  background: #df2721;
  padding: 2px 7px;
 box-shadow: -7px solid red, 7px solid red;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="black">
    SMM pro
    <br>
  </p>
  <h1>
    Полныи курс привлечения клиентов через социальные сети
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: `line-height` поменяйте на `1em` или `1.1em`, например))

Comment: проблем не будет если line-height сделать 1em, но по дизайну там меньше

Answer (score 0):

Текст надо выделить - проверьте

```css
p {
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline;
  background: #000;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

p::selection {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur<br>adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, earum.
</p>
```